# How can I combine string array resources?

Tags: android

In my Android app I have multiple activities using different array resources and I want to create one that has all of them. Is there an easy way to do this so that when I add an item to the string array it is automatically added to the "All" activity?

Comment: do you mean creating one array which can be used by all the activity ?

Comment: @Lucifer Yes, but I don't want to have to copy+paste each item into that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a generalized array in a class called ConstantCodes.java and declare your all arrays in it as follows,

```
public class ConstantCodes
{
       public static String[][] arrayCollection = { { "A11","A22","A33" }, 
                                    { "B11","B22","B33" },
                                    { "C11","C22","C33" } 
                                  };
}
```

**Calling FirstActivity.java**

```
private String[] firstActivityArray = ConstantCodes.arrayCollection[0]; // this will return first stored array on 0th position.
```

**Calling SecondActivity.java**

```
private String[] secondActivityArray = ConstantCodes.arrayCollection[1]; // this will return first stored array on 1st position.
```